# Python: String replacement with REGEX

Tags: python

I am new to python & I want to perform following actions.

I have bunch of text files with statements like

*`insert dynamic-variable;`* 
//Note that *dynamic-variable* is dynamic word i want to use as it is in my replacement statement.

I want to replace above statement with

*`Util.insert(dynamic-variable)`;*

What is best possible way to get this done in python ? I am going through REGEX & Backreferance documentation but some specific direction will be helpful.

So, I am trying something of this sort

```
import re
input = "insert account;"
result = re.sub(r'((?:insert))(\w+);', r'Util.insert(\2);', )
```

result string should be Util.insert(**account**);

```
input = "insert contact;"
result = re.sub(r'((?:insert))(\w+);', r'Util.insert(\2);', )
```

result string should be Util.insert(**contact**);

Comment: please make an attempt and show your attempt before asking

Comment: you don't even need regex for this. Split and reformat your string.

Comment: `"Util.{}({})".format(*s.split())`

Comment: updated my question with my attempt & example..can you check again

Comment: `r'(/\w+/)(/\w+/)', r'Util.insert(\2);'` why the slashes? and don't you want to test against `insert` ?

Comment: yes. I want to check against insert. updated my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(question edited, so first explanation is moot..., but now it's not working because of missing space characters in regex... plus non-capturing group isn't what you need, you need to consume `insert` to replace by `Util.insert`)

Okay, just create one capture group: the variable name

Working regex & example:

```
import re

s = "insert variable;"
print(re.sub("^insert\s+(\w+)",r"Util.insert(\1)",s))
```

prints:

```
Util.insert(variable);
```

`(\w+)` matches any letter, digit and underscore, which probably covers the variables you can define.

Comment: Thanks Jean. This will work i guess. I have to run this script on a directly  of files. I will try this out.

Comment: in that case, you have to use `re.MULTILINE` as an option or work line by line.

Comment: I tried following script..It prints expected output but when i open file..string is not replaced


# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import re;

file = open("testfile.cls", "rw");
for line in file: 
 line = re.sub("insert\s+(\w+)",r"Util.insert(\1)",line,flags=re.IGNORECASE);
 line = re.sub("update\s+(\w+)",r"Util.insert(\1)",line,flags=re.IGNORECASE);
 print line;

file.close();

Comment: you have to write to another file. read-write doesn't work here. And print doesn't write to the file... check SO answers "how to replace strings in a file" sth like that

Answer (score 0):

try the following:-

```
import re

doc='''insert dynamic-variable;
insert dynamic-variable;
insert dynamic;
insert variable;
some more line
insert dynamic-variable;'''

print re.sub(r'insert\s([\w-]*)', r'Util.insert(\1);', doc)
```

Output:-

```
Util.insert(dynamic-variable);
Util.insert(dynamic-variable);
Util.insert(dynamic);
Util.insert(variable);
some more line
Util.insert(dynamic-variable);
```